# While using strutst html tags, how can I call onclick event on submit button?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts, struts-html

I have parent page where there is an element. Onclick of that element popup window comes. On popup window there is one textbox and submit button. Now I want to refresh parent page when submit button on popup window clicked.
I have solution to refresh parent page:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  window.opener.location.reload();
}
```

I have added this script in popup jsp page. So whenever I click on element on parent page, popup window comes and parent page gets refreshed(want to skip this), then I add some text in textbox on popup and submit the data, since it is submit button popup again reloads and parent page gets refreshed(which is expected to happen). Since I am using `window.onload` on popup page, it gets refreshed twice, I want to skip first refresh.
So I decided to perform refresh on click of submit button.
**Popup page JSP code:**

```
<td align="center">
 <html:submit styleId="btn_add" property="submitButton" onclick="formConfirmOff();" value="Add" />
</td>
```

**Another solution I was trying to skip first refresh:**

```
document.getElementById("btn_add").onclick = function(){
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
```

But using above script it gives me error that **cannot set property onclick of null**
so it may be because script is getting executed before DOM loads. so I added script in

```
window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("btn_add").onclick = function(){
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }
    }
```

But when did this shows Confirm Navigation dialog with options Leave this page and stay on this page.
What may be the issue. Does the order of function passed to onclick matters ?
I simply want to refresh parent page when data is added on popup child page using submit button.

**EDIT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#frm_addSpeedData").submit(function(event) {  
        //event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST", //chose your request type method POST or GET
              url: "/webapp/addSpeedDataAction.do", // your struts action url
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              success: function() {
                window.opener.location.reload(); // callback code here
              }
            })
        })
    });
```

Sometimes this code works but sometimes not.
Means when popup opens I submit the data on popup. Then on success parent window gets refreshed. But still I can not see updates on parent page.
what may be the issue ?

Comment: I simply want to refresh parent page when data is added on popup child page using submit button.

Comment: So you want to first execute your server side code and than refresh your parent page ?

Comment: Yes, once done with form submit on popup, refresh parent page

Comment: In my case it seems it is executing the refresh first and then server code, and hence parent page reloads with old data :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this manually using AJAX call to your server and on successful execution you will refresh your parent page.

Below is example of using [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form_selector").submit(function(event) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST", //chose your request type method POST or GET
              url: "Your_Action", // your struts action url
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              success: function() {
                window.opener.location.reload(); // callback code here
              }
        })
   })
});
</script>
```

Here is JavaScript version :

```
var url = "/webfdms/addSpeedDataAction.do";

xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream");
xmlHttp.responseType = "blob";

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == xmlHttp.DONE) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }
    }   
};
xmlHttp.send();
```

Comment: How can I avoid reposting form data ?

Comment: You can use `event.preventDefault()` see my updated answer.

Comment: window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("btn_add").onclick = function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }
    }

can I use like this

Comment: It will also prevent form to submit..!! above code not able to call your server action.

Comment: so what is the best possible way to refresh parent only when data is submitted on popup page

Comment: Ajax call to submit your data and refresh parent after call is success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88543/discussion-between-yagnesh-agola-and-mahendra-kawde).

Comment: Please check updated answer for native JavaScript ajax call.

Comment: Yagnesh my request is of POST type so how can send parameters

Comment: can you tell me what does this line do : $(this).serialize()

Comment: I am using this code(jQuery version) but sometimes it seems that page gets refreshed before values submitted to server.

Comment: Its possible if you wright code in success block.. Please debug it or insert alert in success to check it.

Comment: When added alert to see if it is being called then it works properly. But what it causes to stop work sometimes ?